# porting C++ to C# for decoding a federal gov't FASC-N (Federal Agency Smart Card Number)

Tags: c#, c++, encoding

I need to port a snippet of C++ to C# that decodes some BCD bytes, but I'm pretty new to C#, so I've run into a problem with using the %, >> and & operators.

Here's the encoding description.

> Data on the FASC-N is encoded using a process called Binary Coded
>   Decimal (BCD). It uses 5 bits per character (4 data bits and 1 parity
>   bit) and results in a 16-character set. Encoding the full 40-character
>   FASC-N in BCD digit format results in 200 bits of information. Rather
>   than transmit the data one character at a time, the data can be packed
>   such that each transmitted byte contains 8 meaningful bits (e.g. the
>   full 5 from Character One plus the first 3 from the Character Two).
>   These 200 bits can thus be transmitted in the form of 25 bytes (200
>   bits divided by 8 bits per byte). Thus the 40-character FASC-N becomes
>   a 25-byte BCD encoded transmittal.

I have the 25 byte data and need to decode to 40 bytes.

Here's the C++:

```
byte byBCD, byBCDs, byBits, byShift = 0x80, by, nn;
byte FASCN_ReadChars[40] = {0};

// an example raw FASCN
byte FASCN[25] = { 0xd1, 0x38, 0x10, 0xd8, 0x21, 0x0c, 0x2c, 0xd2, 0x54, 0x88, 0x85, 0xa1, 0x68, 0x58, 0x21, 0x08, 0x42, 0x10, 0x84, 0x30, 0x81, 0x38, 0x10, 0xc3, 0xf3 };

nn = 0;
byBCD = 0;
byBits = 0;
byBCDs = 0;

for (nn = 0; nn < 200; nn++)
{
    if (FASCN[(nn / 8)] & (byShift >> (nn % 8)))    /* Databit = 1 */
        byBCD = (byBCD | (0x01 << (nn % 5)));

    byBits++;    /* bit counter (per 5) */

    if (byBits == 5)
    {                               
        /* each 5 bits is a character */
        for (by = 0; by < NO_OF_ABA_CHARS; by++)
        {
            if (byBCD == abyABAMap[by])
            {
                FASCN_ReadChars[byBCDs++] = by;
                break;
            }
        }

        byBits = byBCD = 0;    /* reset bit counter and byBCD */
    }
}
```

In moving to C# the line below complains, "Cannot implicitly covert type 'int' to 'bool'"

```
if ((FASCN[(nn / 8)]) & (byShift >> (nn % 8)))
```

So I broke that line down into each operation to see which was complaining.

```
byte b1 = FASCN[(nn / 8)];
byte b2 = (nn % 8);
byte b3 = (byShift >> b2);
```

The bottom two gave type errors so I cast them to (byte).

```
byte b2 = (byte)(nn % 8);
byte b3 = (byte)(byShift >> b2);
```

So I tried the if() with b1 and b3, but again get a, "Cannot implicitly covert type 'int' to 'bool'"

```
if(b1 & b3)
```

Any ideas on how design that if statement in C#?

Anyone interested can review the FASCN more by reading sections 5.4, 6.0 and 6.1 of this doc - http://fips201ep.cio.gov/documents/TIG_SCEPACS_v2.2.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C/C++ will treat any non 0 value as true and 0 as false, but C# expects a boolean expression to evaluate to either true or false.

Try the following

```
if (b1 & b2 != 0)
```